# shell script - create a mysql database

Tags: mysql, remote-access, centos6

I am trying to crate a shell script that would:

- connect to a remote server that has MYSQL running
- On success run "CREATE DATABASE foo;"

So far I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h 111.11.11.11 -u root -p'XXXXXXX'
mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
```

or

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE foo;";
```

But no success.

I am using the command line to run the shell script.

```
# sh create_mysql_database.sh
```

but all it does is force mysql to connect and wait for input and that is it.

Anyone knows how to actually achieve this?

```
Server:
Centos 6.2
MySQL client version: 5.1.61
```

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there shouldnt be a space between `-p` and the actual password.

Secondly, as far as I could see from the documentation, you can just add the commands right after the first part, with a -e switch on.

So the final result will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h 111.11.11.11 -uroot -pPASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE foo;"
```

Comment: Hi @Frederik I already tried it and it doesnt work, it will give an error "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'CREATE DATABASE foo;'". In my example above there is no space between the password (-p'XXXXX') and to make sure that it works I tried running it and it connects successfully, but I cannot pass the command inside the shell script.

Comment: Check my updated answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Id use the `mysqladmin` command for this type of task:

```
mysqladmin -u root -pPASSWORD create foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use -e option, like it :

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h 111.11.11.11 -uroot -pPASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE foo;"
```

or :

```
#!/bin/bash
SQL="CREATE DATABASE foo;"
mysql -h 111.11.11.11 -uroot -pPASSWORD <<<$SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, you can create a database without logging into mysql.

For example, to create a DB called `foo`, try the following:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
mkdir foo
chown mysql:mysql foo
```

and you are done !!!